# Problem with StringBuilder C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, development

I am trying to populate a gridview from sharepoint list and population is working good expect in one column i want to display and `<a>` tag

I have the following code:

```
   StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();

   dr["Status"] = cstext.Append("<a>click me</a>");
```

but in my browser i am seeing this `<a>click me</a>` and in inspect element i am seeing this `&lt;a&gt;click me&lt;/a&gt;`

Please help me

Comment: can you try it as `cstext.Append("<a>click me</a>").toString(); ` ?

Comment: @GautamSheth: `ToString` won't help, as it's called anyway before rendering. The problem probably is `HTMLEncode`-ing the content

Comment: A StringBuilder is for **Building** strings, and the `Append()` methods return value is intended for chaining (`value.Append("a").Append("b")` ). Using it in the way you are using it (like a regular System.String) is probably going to lead to other unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is not `StringBuilder`, but the "gridview". Are you using a [`SPGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx)?

If so, the grid is probably encoding the content you put there. If you want to add `HTML` content in a cell set the [`HTMLEncode`-property of your `BoundField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`.

Also, on a sidenote, `dr["Status"] = cstext.Append("<a>click me</a>");` will set the content of the cell to the `StringBuilder`. [`StringBuilder.Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4sc8ca8(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the whole `StringBuilder`.

Comment: i luv u, u saved my life